# Parse - Normal distribution query

Tags: android, ios, parse-platform

So I have a table full of short 3-7 word quotes in my Parse table. I need to grab a certain amount of them to display to the user. The catch is that I want fresh quotes (newer ones) to appear prominently while being mixed in with old quotes, I think this is called normal distribution?

How can I accomplish this in Parse Cloud Code while minimizing the number of API request calls?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will probably want to come up with some kind of ranking or selection scheme for the old quotes which can be queried against. Then those results can be combined with the other query which fetches the newest quotes.

For example, you could have have a selection scheme based on highest quality, highest ranked, most popular, and so on. How you come up with the distribution or selection scheme will be entirely up to you as Parse does not have any methods for it. You could have a counter for the number of views of each quote. Maybe users have the ability to upvote/downvote quotes. It's hard to think about the scope of a selection scheme with limited information on the user experience of the app :)

In terms of implementation, you're correct that you will want to use a cloud code function. Within this function you will perform both queries, merge the results and possibly sort the results before returning them.

With regards to API calls, it's ***always*** best to prioritize the user experience above all else rather than skimping out on functionality to save pennies on API usage. The call to the cloud function from the client app will be 1 request. The two queries can be joined together using a [compound query](https://parse.com/docs/js/guide#queries-compound-queries) (see the example below) which only counts as 1 API request. This brings the total number of requests up to 2.

```
var compoundQuery = new Parse.Query.or(newQuoteQuery, oldQuoteQuery);
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer Russell :) I feel like I should elaborate on what I need. I have to pull random quotes from the Parse table. I need a certain number of the quotes to always be quotes that are dated Today. So I'm not sure a combination query would work for this. So I'm not sure combination queries would work since there's no way I can specify that some of the results MUST match one of the queries. Right now the best solution I can come up with based on questions about random queries is that I do 2 queries. What do you think?

Comment: Sure thing! You're correct about there being uncertainty with the results returned from a query. Queries return 100 objects by default and can be increased up to 1000, however you still have no guarantees which of those will be new ones compared to old ones. The safest approach would be two separate queries and then you can merge the results in cloud code yourself. That will give you full control of the distribution, ordering, and so on.

Comment: This will use another API request to having 3 total (1 to call the cloud function and 2 separate queries), however that's not too extreme and it's worth it to improve the user experience